# How can I give my human scout darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, unearthed-arcana, vision-and-light

I'm currently making a Rogue (Scout) using the human House Orien race from Eberron Unearthed Arcana.

I'm trying to make them good at looking for enemies with a base walking speed of 60ft (race bonus, Scout feat, and Mobile) along with expertise in the Perception and Investigation skills. I want my character to be able to scout for enemies in the dark without requiring a light source which will give my position away to enemies.

How can I give them darkvision without racial features?

Shadow Magic Sorcerer seemed like it might be an solution; is multi-classing to that worth it? Or should I try to go hunting for *goggles of night* or keep a light source around me?

Comment: Which Eberron UA is the human subrace being referenced from? [The Mark of Passage in UA: Dragonmarks](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_Dragonmarks.pdf#page=4)? That seems like the most accurate fit, given that it grants a starting speed of 40 feet (though it was reduced to 35 feet in the final published version), and the Scout rogue's 9th-level Superior Mobility feature and the Mobile feat each increase it by 10 feet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### There are a few multiclassing options that will grant you darkvision.

If you're willing to take 2 levels of Warlock, you can get the *Devil's Sight* Eldritch Invocation, which grants 120 feet of darkvision.  It has the added bonus of penetrating magical darkness.

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, the Gloom Stalker Ranger gains darkvision to a range of 60 feet.  You'll need three levels of Ranger to choose the conclave.  It comes with the added bonus that:

> While in darkness, you are invisible to any creature that relies on darkvision to see you in that darkness.

As you mentioned, it would only take 1 level of Shadow Sorcerer to gain 120 feet of darkvision.

### And some other options.

You already mentioned *[goggles of the night](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/goggles-of-night)*, an uncommon magic item that grants darkvision.

The *[robe of eyes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes)* is a rare magic item that grants darkvision to a range of 120 feet, among other benefits.

A *[belt of dwarvenkind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/belt-of-dwarvenkind)* is another rare magic item that grants 60 feet of darkvision.

If your party has a Wizard of the School of Transmutation, you might be able to ask them to lend you their Transmuter's Stone (6th level sub-class feature), which has the option of granting darkvision to a range of 60 feet.  Alternatively, you could take 6 levels of Wizard yourself.

The 2nd level spell *darkvision* grants darkvision to a range of 60 feet for 8 hours.  It's available to Druids, Rangers, Sorcerers and Wizards.  You could either ask a party member of one of those classes to cast it on you, or take enough levels in one of those classes to be able to cast it on yourself.

Comment: You should add the the 2nd level darkvision spell.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it should be noted that in The Wayfarer's Guide to Eberron, Dragonmarked Humans with the Mark of Finding get 60' Darkvision.

Comment: @Davo But as an Orien that solution is completely off the table. And about the Belt of Dwarvenkind, don't forget about the [glorious beard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127968/is-there-a-maximum-attainable-beard-thickness) that you can have by using it.

Comment: Please note that Devil's Sight does not give darkvision as darkvision is a specific keyword mechanic. It allows you to see normally in the dark. If there is dim light then Devil's Sight has no effect, and your vision is whatever you have in that situation. https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/957031642979221504?s=19

Comment: Now relevant multiclassing option: A 2nd-level Artificer could have goggles of night as one of their infusions. That artificer could also be an ally

Comment: Another multiclassing option: 3 levels in Fighter and selecting Rune Knight as your specialization lets you take the Stone Rune for (effectively) permanent 120ft darkvision.  It's *probably* a worse option than the others, though for some builds that want to lean towards Fighter levels it'll work out well.

Comment: To be accurate, goggles of night is the only Magic Item listed that does NOT require attunement. This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing (and able) to multiclass a level, then Tasha's Cauldron of Everything includes a new and very potent option:

### Multiclass one level of Cleric with the Twilight domain

This gives you the "Eyes of Night" feature which gives you Darkvision with an amazing 300ft! range.

As an added bonus, you can share this Darkvision with your friends for up to one hour per day.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get darkvision via multiclassing would be, as you have stated, a one level dip in Shadow Sorcerer. A number of other classes could also provide you with Darkvision, but would all require more levels to be invested to get there.

There are a few other ways to get darkvision without multiclassing.

**Get a spellcaster friend:**

The 2nd level spell [Darkvision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkvision) will give you the darkvision for 8 hours at a time and is available to Druids, Rangers, Sorcerers and Wizards. If you become an arcane trickser instead of a scout you could take this spell yourself - but not until level 7.

**Use an item, the following all provide darkvision:**

- Goggles of Night
- Belt of Dwarvenkind
- Robe of Eyes
- Various Dragon Masks (from HOTDQ - if allowed by your DM)

Comment: It's worth noting that all the dragon masks are from the HOTDQ adventure and are thus exclusive to it unless the DM chooses to include them.

Answer (score -4):

Just a subtile reminder that Multiclass is an Optional Rule and your DM might not play with that Ruleset.

Magic items are the best option, indeed.

Items as stated before usually boil down to
Goggles of Night
Belt of Dwarvenkind (also very fun and strong)
Robe of eyes (late game-ish for most people)

Comment: Magic item availability is even less certain than multiclassing is :)