# Optimal 5e warlock for DPR/AC with blade pact no multiclass

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, warlock

I'm looking for ideas on the best way to build a 5e blade warlock for melee dps/ac without multiclassing. Feats and variant human are options, point buy for stats up to 15 initial cap.

I'm not so interested in ranged capabilities or which patron (though probably fiend would be optimum) or which race( as long as they're from the PHB or the elemental evil player companion). Sustained DPR versus burst is preferred, and ideally it would survive through leveling.

As opposed to [Optimal Blade Pact Warlock with Fiend Patron for DPR/AC without Multiclassing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55271/optimal-blade-pact-warlock-with-fiend-patron-for-dpr-ac-without-multiclassing) I'll be using either a feat or ability score not both and the starting cap would be 15 not 16.

Comment: Hello and welcome to rpg.se! Please read the [tour] and see the [help]. It's good that you've edited your question in response to comments, but please don't signal your edits in the text. Your current version should be your best version, and there is version history anyway. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text

Comment: I see there's some close votes already, you may want to review http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic to make sure you're asking a build question in a way we can help with.