# warlock blade fiend

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, warlock, paladin

Hello guys I am thinking of making a warlock/paladin character for the upcoming Elemental Evil adventure league. So far I have read up on the fighter 1/warlock 19 build [Optimal Dragonborn Warlock for DPR/AC with Blade pact and Fiend patron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49851/optimal-dragonborn-warlock-for-dpr-ac-with-blade-pact-and-fiend-patron) and i liked the idea of it but wanted to do a paladin instead so i can use any spare spells for the extra smite damage. I am looking for some help in the leveling area (what order i should go to increase optimization) and also debating between a few races. So far what I have nailed down is the following

1. Paladin first level (for the heavy armor and weapon proficiency)
2. Between the Human variant, Half-Orc, or possible Half-Elf
3. Doing standard array for the ability scores
4. Feats and multiclass are fine to do
5. Leaning more towards a Greatsword as my weapon but depending on how far into levels this AL gets might switch to polearm later.

I am thinking of going P/W/P/W/W/W/W for leveling up to 6. If anyone has a different way to level instead let me know. I was thinking of doing the warlock level for 2nd so i have EB for a nice range spell to have in case melee ins't an option right away in a fight.

Let me know what you guys think and any advice or ideas you may have. Thanks

Comment: @Chucklez What is your objective with this build? A paladin with maximum DPR and AC? Are there any additional requirements or objectives?