# DnD 5e Optimal DPR/AC blade pact variant human

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, warlock

How can I get the highest Damage-Per-Round (both melee and ranged using pact weapon and Eldritch Blast) and AC possible (with DPR being more important than AC) with a Variant Human Blade Pact Warlock (Fiend)? Assume the character uses standard ability array or uses point-buy and prioritizes STR, CHA, and CON in that order. Also assume multiclassing and feats are allowed.

Comment: What aspects of: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49851/optimal-dragonborn-warlock-for-dpr-ac-with-blade-pact-and-fiend-patron aren't suited to this question?

Comment: Given the text is *identical* save for race, I'm going to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Good mod-fu! And I thought plagiarism was only a problem in the classroom! :-)

Comment: Happily, I have senses well honed to detect it in both places.

Comment: I have updated my answer to the original question to address the Human Variant possibility.