# Optimize this Dragonborn Dragon Sorc /cleric concept

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

I have a fluffy character concept and I need help fine-tuning crunch to something viable.

The character: A dragonborn full caster (sorcerer) with Dragon Origin and a splash of cleric (Deity: Bahamut).

I need help realizing...

A strategy for optimized melee DPR, based off either the build below or a modified version thereof, as a secondary character focus.  Full-spell casting is still the primary goal of the character, but I am looking for good melee nova options as an acknowledged, normally sub-optimal backup strategy that won't gimp my spell caster focus.

Current build idea (subject to change):

Sorc 1 (Dragon Origin - Color irrelevant at this time)
Cleric 1 (Bahamut, War or Protection Domain)
Sorc 2 - 6 (Bahamut's blessing converts his prior Origin color to Gold. Already have this approval for this switcheroo)

Stats:
STR 14+2 
DEX 8
CON 12
INT 8
WIS 14
CHA 15+1

ASIs: 8-CHA, 16-CHA
Feats: 4-Warcaster , 12-Elemental Adept (Fire)?

The idea was to use Sorcerer metamagic twinning on Greenflame Blade, with the dragon origin CHA to fire damage, to create a martial-ish vibe while using heavy armor and maybe a shield. I'm aware of the paladin/Sorc MC goodness and am deliberately trying not to abuse this and ideally trying get 9th level spells. 
Also, I will be trying to fill a support-ish role in the group, as there is no divine caster and by MC'ing cleric, I snag heals (Healing Word especially) as well as Bless

Comment: To avoid having the question closed as opinion based add an objective definition for "viable" and "optimal". Something like "maximum damage" or "most healing" or "highest melee damage per round".

Comment: Added changes to the goal section at the bottom to better identify a measurable objective, as suggested by nwp above.

Comment: Seems to me like a "help me build my character" question, which is not really supported here, since it's not _A_ question but a series of parameters you're asking the community to assess. Forums (like this one : http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?63-D-amp-D-5e-Next) would better suit your needs.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with this, as I understand how the character should be built from a traditional perspective (read: a full caster).  What I am asking for is not a full character, but rather a strategy for optimized MELEE NOVA DPR using a sorc base.  Perhaps there are spell, feat or class ability combos I haven't considered that would help this specific goal.  It is admittedly a sub-optimal objective for a sorcerer and therefore I am turning to the experts for assistance.

Comment: And I've found quite a few other well answered questions following a similar format here on the stack exchange, most notably the Warlock DPR question here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49851/optimal-dragonborn-warlock-for-dpr-ac-with-blade-pact-and-fiend-patron

Comment: If you goal is to get to 9th level spells, you need to map out what your build idea looks like (in terms of ASI and feats) in the direction of level 17.  Simply starting with what you have is the first piece of the build, but does not address some of the other core pieces.  Suggest you add a few more points on where  you think this needs to go for people to work with.  Lastly, for how long do you need to rely on melee before our spell casting  takes over?  To level 5?  To level 11?  To level 14?

Comment: Good feedback Korvin.  With regards to feats, I've mentioned Warcaster but beyond that, I left it vague as I feed those with more mastery of the system could slot in what's necessary for their vision.  I'll edit in a few points for clarity.  However, regarding your last question, as I've never attempted such a gish build so I don't know when any potential "melee suppliment" to my arsenal will cease to be effective.  Can you give any perspective there?

Comment: @Brandark I am not expert enough in trying to milk gishness out of a caster class to be of any help without a lot of work that, at the moment, I can't dedicate time to. (Harvey has left us some work to do around the house).  Nor have I an example I tried that was successful.